# Running Primefaces Push (WebSockets) on Websphere Portal 7

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-portal, atmosphere, primefaces-push

I'm trying to use Atmosphere Framework based Primefaces Push (with WebSockets) on WebSphere Portal 7 (running on WAS 7, which uses Java EE 5 -> Servlet 2.5). I just read that WAS 7 doesn't support WebSockets (doesn't have a WebSockets API), so I'm looking for some kind of workaround.

Is there anyone who had a similar problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websockets need at least java ee 7 container and servlet 3.1 API level. If you can switch to longpooling in your component you have a chance, otherwise not. It's not a matter of hack, your server needs to support protocol upgrade.

Comment: I guess you are right. I just created a custom PF component using PF4 push classes  and it works on Websphere Portal 7 using long-polling transport. Thanks for your answer.